# Insert an object into unknow object path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I want to insert an object into a somewhat predefined object:

```
var obj = {
    "scripts": {
        "libs":{}
    },
    "plugins":{}
}

//....

function addobj(path, obj){

    console.log(path); // Object {libs: Object}..
    path.push(obj); // TypeError: undefined is not a function

}

// Test cases:
addobj(obj["scripts"],{"test":{}});

console.log(obj);
```

But an error occurs: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` Why is this happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3Tb/

Comment: Path is an object, `push` is an Array method

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

### demo

```
$.extend(path,obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `.push` onto an Object. An Object is a key-value store, therefore you need to assign a key to the object (value) you want to store on the parent object. How you go about achieving that is another question, but something like this might work:

```
function addobj(path, obj, key) {
    path[key || "unnamed"] = obj;
}
```

If you wanted to add `libs` to `scripts` you would do the following:

```
addobj(script, libs, "libs");
```

However given what this `addobj` method *actually does*, my suggestion would be to drop the abstraction altogether, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

```
function addProp(prop, value, targetObject){
    targetObject[prop] = value;
}

addProp('scripts', { test:{}}, obj);
```

Based on your question, you can use this to target a specific property:

```
var obj = {
    "scripts": {
        "libs":{
            "labs": {
                foo: 1
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins":{}
};

function setPropByString(obj, propString, value) {
    if (!propString)
        return obj;

    var prop, props = propString.split('.');

    for (var i = 0, iLen = props.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
        prop = props[i];

        var candidate = obj[prop];
        if (candidate !== undefined) {
            obj = candidate;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    obj[props[i]] = value;
}

setPropByString(obj, 'scripts.libs.labs', { something: 1 });

console.log(obj);
```

Note that this will overwrite the existing prop. So it's propably easier to just extend with jQuery like [@A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370314/598511) suggest.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mn45R/

Comment: what if I want to add it to scrips -> libs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in the way mentioned in the question.

I believe you should create a function, like

```
function Node(key) {
    var currentNode = this;

    this.getKey = function() {
        return key;
    };

    var children = [];

    this.addNode(childKey) {
        children[children.length] = new Node(childKey);
    }

    this.search(searchKey) {
        if (searchKey === key) {
            return currentNode;
        }
        for (var childIndex in children) {
            var searchResult = children[childIndex].search(searchKey);
            if (!!searchResult) {
                return searchResult;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can create your root this way:

```
var root = new Node();
```

You can add a child to the root this way:

```
root.addNode("scripts");
```

This function can be used to add some node to another node having a key

```
function addNodeToTree(tree, key, newKey) {
    var node = tree.search(key);
    if (!!node) {
        node.addNode(new Node(newKey));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finally, you can add a node like this:

```
addNodeToTree(root, "scripts", "test");
```